# Am I eligible to travel to the Netherlands on a 6 month university exchange using the WHS?

Tags: visas, netherlands, study, australian-citizens

I'm going to Holland in a couple of months on an exchange with my university, and have been advised that I can simply apply for a WHS (working holiday scheme) visa on arrival, as opposed to going for the MVV and residence permit.

If someone with knowledge of these matters could confirm or deny this, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is your citizenship?

Comment: You would be effectively wasting the working holiday opportunity which is a once-in-a-lifetime deal.

Comment: Sorry guys, been away on a hike. I am Australian, which is why the WHS visa applies for me in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need an MVV, period.  This is true whether you are applying under the working holiday scheme or as a student.  Nationals of Australia (and of Canada, Japan, Monaco, New Zealand, South Korea, the United States of America and the Vatican City) simply do not require an MVV in any case.  See http://www.the-netherlands.org/shared/products-and-services/products-and-services/visa---long-stay-mvv:

> You are not required to obtain an MVV if you are a national of Australia, Canada, Japan, Monaco, New Zealand, South Korea, the USA or Vatican City. Instead, your host in the Netherlands can apply for your residence permit before you arrive in the Netherlands. You may also apply for a residence permit yourself after you have arrived in the Netherlands.

Answer (score 4):

[Kingdom of the Netherlands](http://unitedkingdom.nlembassy.org/passports-visas--consular/visas/working-holiday-scheme) has:

> The Working Holiday scheme between the Netherlands and Australia, New
>   Zealand and Canada offers an opportunity to young people from these
>   countries to visit the Netherlands for a period of up to twelve months
>   with the objective of combining a holiday with work experience, thus
>   supplementing their financial resources during their stay.
>
> Please note: you can only make use of this scheme once.
>
> Eligibility
>
> To qualify for the Working Holiday scheme applicants must comply with the
>   following conditions
>
> - be an Australian, Canadian or New Zealand national
> - be aged between 18 and 30 years, both inclusive, at the time of   application (you must enter the Netherlands and register at the
>     Immigration and Naturalisation Service before you turn 31)
> - have a national passport valid for at least fifteen months
> - have a full medical insurance cover for the Netherlands valid for a minimum of twelve months from date of entry into the Netherlands
> - have a return air ticket or sufficient funds to purchase one, and
> - not be accompanied by children.

You can travel to the Netherlands without mvv and apply for a residence permit after arrival. A fee will have to be paid for the residence permit.

The requirements for the [working holiday scheme](http://unitedkingdom.nlembassy.org/binaries/content/assets/postenweb/v/verenigd_koninkrijk_van_groot_brittannie_en_noord_ierland/nederlandse-ambassade-in-londen/import/paspoort_visa_consulair/requirements-mvv-working-holiday.pdf) are:

> **CHECK-LIST MVV WORKING HOLIDAY**
>
> - Valid passport (Australian, New Zealand or Canadian, applicant between 18 and 30 years inclusive)
> - Completed and signed MVV-application form (signature same as in passport)
> - One photograph (meeting all photo requirements)
> - Copy of original valid UK residence permit (if applicable) or copy of UK entry stamp
> - Copy of applicant’s passport (holder page, signature page)
> - Proof of funds (sufficient to buy a ticket home) or a ticket home
> - Medical insurance or medical insurance declaration

Comment: Thanks @pnuts. I meet all the conditions; the reason I ask is that I have been unable to find anything in the host university recommendations around using the WHS for the exchange program, despite the fact that the Department of Immigration specifically recommends it for this type of educational experience.

Comment: It is bizarre that your first source notes that the MVV is not necessary, while the second lists it as a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @pnuts comprehensive response, [**Expatica explains**](http://www.expatica.com/nl/visas-and-permits/Study-in-the-Netherlands-Dutch-student-visas-and-permits_108430.html) how to get the correct visa (how easy it is, that the school will apply, and that it can be accomplished before arrival):

> **Dutch student visa**
>
> Depending on your nationality, you may need a provisional residence permit (MVV) to enter the Netherlands, in addition to a Dutch residence permit to stay in the country for more than three months. Since 2013, the educational establishment (your recognised sponsor) can apply for both permits in one application, through the Entry and Residence Procedure (TEV). You can find out if you need an MVV for entering the Netherlands in Expatica's guide to [Dutch provisional residence permits (MVV) and temporary residence permits](http://www.expatica.com/nl/visas-and-permits/Getting-a-Dutch-visa-or-temporary-residence-permit_108412.html).
>
> Different rules apply for citizens from the European Union (EU), the European Economic Area (EEA – EU plus Iceland, Liechtenstein and Norway) and Switzerland – plus their family members. If this applies to you, read Expatica's [guide for EU/EEA/Swiss nationals moving to the Netherlands.](http://www.expatica.com/nl/visas-and-permits/EU-EEA-Swiss-citizens-moving-to-the-Netherlands_108413.html)

Comment: @pnuts exactly, but handy for the next one who asks exactly the same, never to return (I call them hit-and-run)

Comment: Sorry @Dorothy, back again now. I was referring specifically to the WHS visa which I believe is a bilateral program between the Netherlands and Australia. I was hoping to bypass the TEV and MVV, and was wondering whether the WHS would allow me to do so.

Comment: @Neuw no problem but, as Roddy of the Frozen Peas points out, if the WHS is a one-off, why use it to study; have the uni get the study/residence and then go for the WHS for another wonderful year in the Netherlands.